# AES encryption and decryption wiht salted key

Tags: java, key, aes, salt

I can't decrypt file with different salt and same password. Mybe I don't understand the concept. How does it work? Should I store static salt?

```
public static SecretKey getKeyFromPassword(String password) throws Exception {
    byte[] salt = "123456".getBytes();
    //SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    //random.nextBytes(salt);

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
    return secret;
}
```

Comment: A different salt results in a different key. Therefore, yes, you must store the (random) salt so that it is available for decryption. The salt is not secret and is usually concatenated with the ciphertext (analogous to the IV). The separation is based on the known lengths of salt (and IV).

Comment: Ok, that sounds good.